# Hover disabled after style change: important doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

My problem is as follows: I have a clickable div with a `background-image` that changes (the image) on `:hover`.

This div kind of represents a menu button. When the div is pressed a script is executed that changes the `background-image` too.

However, I want the hover to still work after running this script. I have read about the style priorities and that I should use `!important` with the hover. I have used this before without problems, but for some reason the hover doesn't work, even with `!important`. Does this have something to do with `background-image`, can't this be combined with `!important`?

The div:

```
<a href="#" onclick="open_Thema(1);">
    <div id="venster_Links_Menu_1">
        <div class="venster_Links_Menu_Tekst">Introductie</div>
    </div>
</a>
```

The css:

```
#venster_Links_Menu_1 {
    margin: 0;
    height: calc((100%/6) - 1px);
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url(images/Thema_1_Half.png);
    background-size: cover;
    position:relative;
}

#venster_Links_Menu_1:hover {
    background-image: url(images/Thema_1.png); !important
}
```

And the script:

```
<script>

    var themaOud = 0;

    function init(){
    }

    function open_Thema(themaNieuw){
        if (themaOud != 0)
        {
            document.getElementById("venster_Links_Menu_"+themaOud).style.backgroundImage="url(images/Thema_"+themaOud+"_Half.png)";
        }
        document.getElementById("venster_Links_Menu_"+themaNieuw).style.backgroundImage="url(images/Thema_"+themaNieuw+".png)";
        themaOud = themaNieuw;
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Based on your story: 1) Post code. 2) You can probably just use the pseudo-elements `:focus` and `:active` instead of running a script?

Comment: My bad, added it to the first post.

Comment: `!important` is not a good practice.

Comment: @devgaspa what alternatives would you recommend in this case?

Comment: @NeoSyp the `:hover` does not work after the click because your script declares the inline style (inside the html tag) this makes the style background be immutable. You will need to create a more elaborate script. I will try to do something.

Comment: @NeoSyp [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/devgaspa/z78wj6rn/) that's it?

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to write an important would be

`!important;`

not

`; !important`

Notice the placement of the semicolon.

Comment: Ha, how the smallest things can have the biggest impact. Totally fixed it, thank you!